# How to concatenate value from for loop to empty string

Tags: string, for-loop, key, string-concatenation

I am trying to find "lat" and "lon" keys in IP data dictionary and then add the values of those keys to empty "lat" and "lon" variables. Then add them in google variable, to get working google maps link. Please help.

import requests

```
r = requests.get(f"http://ip-api.com/json/50.40.70.18?fields=24895487")
data = r.json()
print(data)
lat = ""
lon = ""
google = f"https://maps.google.com?q={lat},{lon}"
for key, value in data.items():
    if key == 'lat':
        lat += str(value)
    if key == 'lon':
        lon += str(value)
print(google)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lat = data.get("lat")
lon = data.get("lon")
google = f"https://maps.google.com?q={lat},{lon}"
```